# Redirecting sed matches to individual files

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, bioinformatics

I have a file containing a list of DNA sequence names and another containing DNA sequences. They look like this:

```
$ cat list.txt
seq1
seq3

$ cat sequences.txt
>seq1
AAAAA
AAAAA
>seq2
CCCCC
CCCCC
CCCCC
>seq3
TTTTT
```

I want to retrieve only seq1 and seq2 (listed on list.txt) and redirect them to individual files. As you can see, each sequence has different number of lines hence I cannot just say to 'sed' to pick up N number of lines after each match. I want my output like this:

```
$ ls
seq1.txt
seq2.txt

$ cat seq1.txt
>seq1
AAAAA
AAAAA
$ cat seq2.txt
>seq3
TTTTT
```

I am using this:

```
while read list
do
names=$(echo $list)
        sed '/$list/,/>/{/>/q}' "$PWD/sequences.txt" > "$names".dna
done < list.txt
```

However, the output is:

```
$ ls
seq1.txt
seq2.txt

$ cat seq1.txt
>seq1
AAAAA
AAAAA
>seq3
TTTTT

$ cat seq2.txt
>seq1
AAAAA
AAAAA
>seq3
TTTTT
```

The script is creating individual files but all contain all the matches, not individuals as I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shell variables don't expand inside single quotes - so it's trying to match `$list` as a regex (which fails resulting in the default printing of the whole file)?

Comment: See `fastaexplode` from Guy Slater's `exonerate` suite of bioinformatics tools. Also, [the Bioinformatics StackExchange site](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Can't do this with sed alone. But with awk:

```
awk '
    # remember the wanted sequences
    NR == FNR {seqs[$1]; next}

    $1 ~ /^>/ {
        # get the sequence name
        seq = $1
        sub(/^>/, "", seq)
        p = 0
        # if it is in the list, set up the file to print to
        if (seq in seqs) {
            f = seq ".txt"
            p = 1
        }
    }
    p {print > f}
' list.txt sequences.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
command

awk '$1 ~ /seq1/{f=1}$1~/seq2/{f=0;exit}f' sequences.txt  >seq1.txt

sed -n '/seq3/,$p' sequences.txt > seq2.txt
```

output

```
cat seq1.txt
seq1
AAAAA
AAAAA

cat seq2.txt
seq3
TTTTT
```